# Problem using Kaniko to build containers from a Kubernetes CloudBees Jenkins shared-library

Tags: kubernetes, dockerfile, jenkins-shared-libraries, kaniko

I am trying to build containers using a Jenkins shared-library that calls Kaniko. Jenkins is CloudBees Core running on a Kubernetes cluster.

I prefer to try to use pod templates to build containers, but I can fall back to a dedicated VM if I have to (but my client will not be happy).

**The problem**: running Kaniko from a simple `Jenkinsfile` pipeline works fine, but I am getting errors when trying to run it from a `shared-library`.

The snippet of my shared-library:

```
docker.image('kaniko').inside('-u root --privileged') {
       sh '''#!/busybox/sh
            /kaniko/executor --context `pwd` --destination docker.artifactory.company.com/docker-local/hello-kaniko:latest
            '''
    }
```

The error I get (snipped):

```
.
.
.
Building: default
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . kaniko
/home/jenkins/workspace/cloud-services@tmp/durable-28d8debd/script.sh: line 1: docker: not found
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker pull kaniko
/home/jenkins/workspace/cloud-services@tmp/durable-dc065568/script.sh: line 1: docker: not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

Has anyone else been able to get Kaniko running from a shared-library in Jenkins on Kubernetes?

Comment: Hi , Is the docker on your PATH `docker: not found`?

Comment: I can run other containers from a Jenkinsfile, but having trouble with the shared-library.

Comment: could you please post your Jenkinsfile / full Pipeline?

Comment: I am using a shared library, so the Jenkinsfile is VERY minimal and probably won't help at all. But if you have experience running Kaniko from a shared library, I would appreciate what the code looked like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in kaniko container, what i had to do was add PATH to the environment:

```
    withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/busybox:/kaniko']) {
      sh '''#!/busybox/sh
      /kaniko/executor (....)
    }
```

Comment: **NOTE**: I moved the code out of a shared library and back into the Jenkinsfile pipeline and had no issues. So I am marking this as the accepted answer because I hate when questions live forever without those green checkmarks...